# Which Verb form shall we use to describe completed / Finished Action referring to Present tense

Tags: present-tense

Scenario,

I Change the date of program and wanted to inform to my friends. Which Tense Should I use?

*........That is why I change this date.*

Is the above sentence construction is correct to describe present tense?

This because I want to describe changes are pertains to Present situation. Thought at the time of saying date changes are already done by me.

Still can we use Present tense or shall we use Past Tense.

*That is why I changed this date.*

I got this confusion because of Sentence like.

I Like It very much. ( Present Tense )

I Liked it very much. ( Past Tense)

Answer (score -1):

There are two equally valid ways to say what you want:

> That is why I changed the date.
>
> That is why I am changing the date.

You cannot use the present simple. Why not? Because the present simple indicates things that happen and *continue to happen* repeatedly, or are permanent, habitual or long term arrangements. For instance "I own a shop" (I own a shop and will do so long term), or "I often change the date" (I am in the habit of changing dates). In your sentence, however, we are dealing with a short term action.

Technically, if you have already changed the date, then past tense is most accurate. You have already changed the date. However, "I am changing" - the present progressive - is also acceptable. It suggests you are in the process of changing the date, and have already begun the process of changing it.

Comment: Happy to correct this if anyone wants to tell me what the downvote was for.